# Nvidia Nsight 4.0 cannot profile code in OpenGL 4.3

Tags: opengl, profiling, nvidia, nsight

I am using Visual Studio 13 with Nvidia NSights 4.0. In my application I am doing a mix of different types of rendering but, for the purpose of testing the proiler, I did a simple rendering of a scene. I opened the graphics debugger and, when I open the GUI and press spacebar to capture the frame I get this error:

Cannot enter frame debugger. Nsight only supports frame debugging for
D3D9, D3D10, D3D11, and OpenGL 4.2.
Reason: glEnd

I am using a GT540m and I checked my OpenGL version and it is 4.3
If I, then, try to use the performance anaysis tool and trace OpenGL (following the instructions) I always get some percentage of CPU frames and 0 GPU frames.

I have no idea what am I doing wrong. Is there any solution to this or alternative ways to profile OpenGL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using immediate mode drawing? Ie. glBegin(..); glVertex<> ; glEnd()

From the [Nsight User Guide's Supported OpenGL Functions page](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/index.html#developertools/desktop/graphics_ogl_functions.htm%3FTocPath%3DDeveloper%2520Tools%7CDesktop%2520Developer%2520Tools%7CNVIDIA%2520Nsight%2520Visual%2520Studio%2520Edition%7CNVIDIA%2520Nsight%2520Visual%2520Studio%2520Edition%25204.0%7CGraphics%2520Debugger%7CFrame%2520Debugger%2520(OpenGL)%7C_____6):

> NVIDIA® Nsight™ Visual Studio Edition 4.0 frame debugging supports the set of OpenGL operations, which are defined by the OpenGL 4.2 core profile. Note that it is not necessary to create a core profile context to make use of the frame debugger. An application that uses a compatibility profile context, but restricts itself to using the OpenGL 4.2 core subset, will also work. A few OpenGL 4.2 compatibility profile features, such as support for alpha testing and a default vertex array object, are also supported.

So, replace the immediate mode rendering with newer drawing functions like glDrawArrays and glDrawElements that vertex array objects.

Better yet, create a core profile context to ensure you aren't using deprecated functionality.

My advice: stay away from outdated tutorials online and read the latest edition of the Red book (OpenGL Programming Guide), which only covers modern OpenGL.

You can also try the more basic [GPUView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj585574(v=vs.85).aspx) tool that can be found in [Win 8 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/hh852363)

**UPDATE:**

As for why 0 GPU frames are retrieved, are you sure that your GPU is on the [list of supported hardware](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition-requirements). I had the same problem where NSight was mostly working (was able to profile other aspects) but 0 GPU frames were collected. Later realized that my card was not officially supported.

Comment: I am using glDrawElements but I have some code copied from other tutorials so I might do a deep check. Thanks (I already found that I was rendering a quad using glBegin and glend)
BTW, is the core profile only for shaders or I can use it in the host? Cause I have a ARB_compatibility enabled on my shaders.

Comment: Now it seems to work, even if it's giving me a warning "Insufficient OpenGL version", version:unknown. I have 4.3 installed, maybe NSight is not detecting something?

Comment: What about the performance analysis tool? I still get 0 GPU frames out of it

Comment: As far as I know, Context versions & profiles are independent of the shader GLSL version and profile. Context profile specification will depend on the windowing toolkit (check the doc section on creation and intializing windows). For GLUT, use glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);

Answer (score 0):

Now available Nsight 4.5 RC1, works with cuda sdk 7 RC, and among its features, now support openGL 4.3 !